# No se muestra mi gráfica

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gráficas

Estoy empezando a aprender python con Sublime text, pero al ejecutar el archivo no se muestra la ventana de la gráfica que hice, aquí les dejo lo que escribí:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(-5,5,0.05)
y=np.cos(x)

plt.show()
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias :(.

Comment: Bueno, no has dicho que quieres graficar, asi que no hay nada que mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

En matplotlib, para mostrar un gráfico, tienes que decir qué quieres mostrar, ya que si tuvieras 3 o más variables, matplotlib no sabría cuales son las buenas.

Por esto, tendrías que poner un comando tipo `plt.plot(x,y)`, que me imagino que quieres hacer el gráfico con x, y.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(-5,5,0.05)
y=np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

El `plot` lo que hace es hacer el gráfico de líneas. En caso de que quieras hacerlo de otra manera, tienes esta página con muchos ejemplos: https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/index.html

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlJxJ.png

Este sería el resultado que me ha salido.

Comment: Sería útil incluir el gráfico generado por el código.

Comment: Buenas, ya te he insertado el gráfico que me ha salido de resultado, aunque si copias el código te debería salir el mismo resultado.